# Using PHP's built in server with subdomains

Tags: php

I'm used to use `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080` while developing, because it saves me some time configuring a real web server. Until today I didn't miss anything about it, but now I need to develop a function that uses subdomains.

I must access `http://foo-bar.localhost:8080` and make php see the request, because I'm trying to implement [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#rules-with-server-names).

Also, `foo-bar` is dynamic (like the `language` subdomain in the documentation of Yii2 I linked) so I need php to be able to handle all subdomains of `localhost`.

Is that possible? How?

Comment: This isn't a question of the http server, be it builtin or not, but of your network setup. If the hostname is resolved correctly, then the requests reaches the server. So check what that hostname `foo-bar.localhost` is resolved to. Adjust that in your systems networking configuration, if required.

Comment: @arkascha I thought about this, but it is not working. I added `127.0.0.1 foo-bar.localhost` to my `hosts`file, but php doesn't see the requests. `ping` is able to resolve.

Comment: Ping is mostly useless for networking diagnostics. Use telnet instead: `telnet foo-bar.localhost 8080`. Does it connect or not? What is the reply?

Comment: @arkascha Nope, telnet isn't resolving. How should I route it?

Comment: What _is_ the exact result?

Comment: @arkascha $ `telnet foo-bar.localhost:8080
telnet: could not resolve foo-bar.localhost:8080/telnet: Name or service not known`

Comment: @arkascha Oh, sorry, there was a typo in my command. It does resolve actually: `$ telnet foo-bar.localhost 8080 \n
Trying 127.0.0.1... \n
Connected to foo-bar.localhost. \n
Escape character is '^]'. \n
^CConnection closed by foreign host`

Comment: Ah, that is better, you realized yourself, great! That looks like an http server, actually. No idea why it disconnects. Works for me locally.

Comment: @arkascha So, telnet is able to resolve, which means that PHP should see the requests, but it doesn't. What could be wrong?

Comment: As said: works for me locally. I checked and I can use a hostname ("subdomain") with the builtin php server. Maybe you just have a caching issue in your browser? Or your browser resolves different? Maybe using a proxy?

Comment: I would make a variable out of `http://foo-bar.localhost:8080` and point it to local server during development

Comment: @arkascha Indeed. It was Chrome, once again, trying to be too smart, caching the address of "already resolved" urls.

Comment: So things work all right now? Great! You made it! BTW: installing an apache http server is a single command. Sure that is too much hassle? :-)

Comment: @arkascha Yup, everything works now :) Thank you! The install part is easy. The config is what takes me too much as I'm changing projects every few hours. Laziness is another factor too...